# TWILIO - why the actual response returned does not match with documented

Tags: twilio, twilio-php

I have integrated Twilio and it works fine. Now I want to capture all the intermediate message statuses. I referred to [Sending Messages.](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/messaging/send-messages)

My code looks like -

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';    
      // Use the REST API Client to make requests to the Twilio REST API
      use Twilio\Rest\Client;

// Your Account SID and Auth Token from twilio.com/console
$sid = '****************';
$token = '*****************';
$client = new Client($sid, $token);

// send message
$message = $client->messages->create(
    // the number you'd like to send the message to
    '+1xxxxxxxxx',
    array(  
        'from' => '+1xxxxxxxx', 
        'body' => 'Test web hook message '.date('h:i'),
        'statusCallback' => "https://xxxxxx/xxxx.php", 
    )
);
```

But the output/response returned to statusCallback is different as -

```
"{\"SmsSid\":\"SM72478c1ea61f467dbc33338123c0ad0\",\"SmsStatus\":\"sent\",\"MessageStatus\":\"sent\",\"To\":\"+1xxxxxxxx\",\"MessageSid\":\"SM72478c1ea612222dbc3b7858123c0ad0\",\"AccountSid\":\"ACb655a10c1c2222e4af158c5395d64beb\",\"From\":\"+1xxxxxxx\",\"ApiVersion\":\"2010-04-01\"}"
```

But I need the response as it is defined at [Sending Messages](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/messaging/send-messages)

**EDIT**

If checked at [Sending Messages](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/messaging/send-messages), we can see the fields returned in the output are - account_sid, api_version, body, num_segments, num_media, date_created, date_sent, date_updated, direction, error_code, error_message, from, price, sid, status, to and uri.
But I receive fields as - SmsSid, SmsStatus, MessageStatus, To, MessageSid, AccountSid, From and ApiVersion.

For me, the fields - num_segments, date_sent, direction, error_code, error_message are important which I am not receiving. Do I need to use another API of TWILIO to retrieve this information ?

Why am I getting different response ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're expecting to see here. Are you saying you are receiving a request to your webhook for the status callback as a JSON body?

Comment: Please check, I have updated my question. I am receiving response to my webhook, but the fields which I receive does not match the fields defined in the output of the example code at Twilio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When you send a message and set a `statusCallback` URL [the sending messages documentation says](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/messaging/send-messages#optional-parameters):

> Twilio will POST the `MessageSid` along with the other [standard request parameters](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms/twilio_request#request-parameters) as well as `MessageStatus` and `ErrorCode`.

The [standard request parameters](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms/twilio_request#request-parameters) are:

- `MessageSid`
- `SmsSid`
- `AccountSid`
- `MessagingServiceSid`
- `From`
- `To`
- `Body`
- `NumMedia`

as well as some others specifically about media or geographic data based on the two numbers.

If you need to find out those other attributes of the message, you will need to [look up the message using the REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/messaging/message#message-instance-resource).

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: I tried to use  Message resource as indicated in your answer, but it returned data only once. I am using same code as given at - https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/messaging/message#message-instance-resource. What can be the reason ? Whenever status callback is invoked, will it always return data ?

Comment: You should make the call to the message resource each time you get a webhook to the status callback URL. That way you will get the latest data on the message itself each time you need it.

Comment: My question was in regards with the fields listed in documents. The document (https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/messaging/message#message-instance-resource) shows field "ErrorCode", which actually is returned as "errorCode". All fields with two words should be referred camel case with first letter in lower case.

Comment: The field names actually refer to the original names of the fields in the [XML output](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/messaging/message?code-sample=code-get-a-message&code-language=output-xml). The JSON output is different, and when the attributes are read into an object in the library of your language choice they are translated to whatever the language's idiomatic attribute style is.

Answer (score 0):

What does your code for your callback url script look like?

What you have is just an escaped JSON string, so to match what you see on the documentation you just have to do this:

```
$json = '{\"SmsSid\":\"SM72478c1ea61f467dbc33338123c0ad0\",\"SmsStatus\":\"sent\",\"MessageStatus\":\"sent\",\"To\":\"+1xxxxxxxx\",\"MessageSid\":\"SM72478c1ea612222dbc3b7858123c0ad0\",\"AccountSid\":\"ACb655a10c1c2222e4af158c5395d64beb\",\"From\":\"+1xxxxxxx\",\"ApiVersion\":\"2010-04-01\"}';
echo stripslashes($json);
```